# Upload large file (>4MB) with asp.net 5.0 app hosted on windows azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-roles, iis-8

I want to upload a large file ( >4mb ) to my asp.net 5.0 app, everything works great on my computer using this config :

```
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxQueryString="2000">
          </requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"  />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400000" />
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

But on azure ( Web Role ) it only works for files under 4MB.

I think that IIS is fine, it's Kestrel or the webListner which doesn't want to process the request ( I get "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process." ), I don't know if it possible to configure it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like another limit being hit. The system.web section is ineffective on ASP.NET 5 applications

Comment: Any idea how to configure the max request length for Kestrel ?

Comment: It was azure storage upload method that blocked my transfer, I solved it by sending the blob with smaller blocks. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

From this article ([vNext maxRequestLength](http://forums.asp.net/t/2023967.aspx?vNext%20maxRequestLength)):

There are no predefined configurations in ASP.NET 5.0 :

- All configuration is done in code
- There is no System.Web in ASP.NET 5.0.
- You can still use web.config for IIS settings only
- **Support for MaxRequestLength is coming**